# How to get a loop through objects to return an object instead of string?

Tags: javascript

I have an object, cards, which is made up of other objects.

When I loop through cards, I expect other objects to get returned. Instead, only a string is returned. I've included what gets returned inline in the code below.

```
console.log(typeof cards); //returns object
console.log(cards); //returns the 3 objects: [Object, Object, Object]
console.log(cards.length); //returns 3

for (var card in cards){
    console.log(typeof card); //returns 0,1,2 as a string, but it should return another object
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops iterate properties of an object, not values.

For example:

```js
var cards = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for(var prop in cards) {
    console.log(prop);        //  0,   1,   2
    console.log(cards[prop]); // 'a', 'b', 'c'
}
```

Moreover, note that `for...in` loops are a [bad way of iterating arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1529630).

ECMAScript 6 introduces [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loops, which iterate values:

```js
var cards = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for(var val of cards) {
    console.log(val);         //  'a', 'b', 'c'
}
```